# Selenium IE WebDriver only works while debugging

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11

I am using Java Gradle, Selenium 3.8.0 and IEWebDriver 3.8.0.

Chrome and Firefox are working fine, but IE throws a `org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed` Exception, although IE also works fine, if I debug my source code step by step.

Therefore I debuged a long time to find that problem and I noticed that IE looses the connection between WebDriver and Source Code, whenever a `webDriver.get(..)` is called, whichs looks like that:

```
driver.get(url);
waitForPageLoaded(driver);
```

Because of that I assume that there are some timing issues, but I already tried to handle this:

```
public void waitForPageLoaded(WebDriver driver) {
        logger.debug("Wait until the page was loaded.");
        // IE seems to fail here.
        new WebDriverWait(driver, SeleniumConfigurator.TIME_OUT)
                .until(d -> ((JavascriptExecutor)d).executeScript("return document.readyState")
                        .equals("complete"));
    }
```

Then I noticed that IE needs some more configuration settings, but I am not allowed to setup some of them: IT restrictions -> I cannot change regedit entries.

BUT, why does it work fine, while debugging?

This is my IE setup:

```
case IE:
                path = "../../../../../../resources/driver/win/IEDriverServer_32_v3-8-0.exe";
                url = getClass().getResource(path);
                if (url == null) {
                    logger.error("Could not find the Internet Explorer web driver binary at " + path + " ." +
                            "All test for this browser will be ignored.");
                    currentBrowserType = BrowserType.UNDEFINED;
                    break;
                }
                try {
                    System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", Paths.get(url.toURI()).toFile().getAbsolutePath());
                } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                // https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/13077/unable-to-run-selenium-webdriver-script-in-ie11
                InternetExplorerOptions optionsIE = new InternetExplorerOptions();
                optionsIE.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
                optionsIE.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
                optionsIE.withAttachTimeout(SeleniumConfigurator.TIME_OUT, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

                //optionsIE.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.REQUIRE_WINDOW_FOCUS, true);


                webDriver = new InternetExplorerDriver(optionsIE);
                currentBrowserType = BrowserType.IE;
                break;
```

I have no idea what's going wrong here..

The first test works fine, after that the timeout exception appears (take a look at the comment):

```
@Test
    public void test_Contact() {
        Init();

        util.logTestStart("Test contact on index page..");
        String xPath = "//*[@id='contact-link']/a";
        WebElement element = webDriver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
        Assert.assertEquals(element.getAttribute("href"), "mailto:what@ever.com");
    }


    @Test
    public void test_LegalInformation() {
        Init();

        util.logTestStart("Test legal information on index page..");
        String xPath = "//*[@id='link-highlighted']/a";
        util.aTagClickByXPath(webDriver, xPath);

        Assert.assertEquals(webDriver.getCurrentUrl(), "http://whatever.com/");
    }


private void Init() {
        if (configurator == null) {
            configurator = SeleniumConfigurator.getInstance();
        }

        if (webDriver != configurator.getWebDriver()) {
            webDriver = configurator.getWebDriver();
        }

        if (util == null) {
            util = new SeleniumTestUtil();
        }

        // Open localhost as default
        util.goTo(webDriver, "http://localhost:8080/de/index");
    }

public void aTagClickByXPath(WebDriver driver, String xPath) {
        logger.debug("Performing a click on an a-Tag, xPath: " + xPath);
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xPath));
        element.click(); // First click works, second one fails, cause of Timeout Exception
        waitForPageLoaded(driver);
    }
```

Does anyone have a hint?

**EDIT:**

`org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchWindowException: Unable to get browser` get thrown for now. Timeout Exception didnt appears anymore. I changed nothing.

**EDIT2:**

Further information:

Node:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" id="link-container">
                <div id="bike-link" class="pull-right">
                    <a href="http://whatever.com/?lang=D">
                        whatever
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="link-highlighted" class="pull-right">
                    <a href="http://whatever2.com/"> <!-- this one -->
                         Rechtliche Hinweise
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div id="contact-link" class="pull-right">
                    <a href="mailto:what@ever.com">
                        Kontakt
                        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Timeout definition:

```
public static final int TIME_OUT = 15;
```

Comment: Can you show us the node `String xPath = "//*[@id='link-highlighted']/a";`?

Comment: Sure, I updated the question; see: Edit 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of facts which you may have to consider as follows :

- First of all:

  ```
  public void waitForPageLoaded(WebDriver driver)
  ```

  looks to me as a pure overhead. There is basically no need to write a separate wrapper function on top of *WebDriverWait*.
- As per the current implementation of *WebDriverWait* in *Selenium v3.8.1* the *Constructors* are as follows :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, Clock clock, Sleeper sleeper, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepTimeOut) 
  WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds)
  WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis)
  ```

  It is pretty much unclear how you have implemented:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, SeleniumConfigurator.TIME_OUT)
  ```

  The arguments looks error prone.
- Again, the until condition

  ```
  d -> ((JavascriptExecutor)d).executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete")
  ```

  is a overhead because the *Client* (i.e. the *Web Browser*) will never return the control back to the `WebDriver` instance until and unless `'document.readyState'` is equal to `"complete"`. Once this condition is fulfilled [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) performs the next line of code. Hence the function

  ```
  Boolean org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(Function<? super WebDriver, Boolean> arg0)
  ```

  will have no impact.
- It's worth to mention that though the *Client* (i.e. the *Web Browser*) can return back the control to the [WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079120/what-is-the-difference-between-chromedriver-and-webdriver-in-selenium/48080871#48080871) instance once `'document.readyState' equal to "complete"` is achieved, it doesn't guarantees that all the `WebElements` on the new [HTML DOM](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) are *VISIBLE*, *INTERACTABLE* and *CLICKABLE*.
- Finally, to address your main issue, I needed a clarification about  the node `xPath = "//*[@id='link-highlighted']/a"` to ensure whether invoking `click()` opens a new tab or url gets redirected. I don't see you handling either of the cases.

---

### Solution

- While dealing with *InternetExplorer*, keep in mind  *InternetExplorerDriver* runs in a real browser and supports Javascript.
- Set the **Browser Focus** through :

  ```
  capabilities.setCapability("requireWindowFocus", true);
  ```
- If `click()` opens a new window, *switch()* through the `window_handles`

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Do we have any generic function to check if page has completely loaded in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327132/do-we-have-any-generic-function-to-check-if-page-has-completely-loaded-in-seleni/50329056#50329056)
- [Selenium how to manage wait for page load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60057676/selenium-how-to-manage-wait-for-page-load/60060481#60060481)

Comment: Thank you for your very helpful information. I'll consider that.

Comment: I know that, but IE still dont want to work, although I considered your help.