# Python Selenium: Switch tab without waiting for page to load

Tags: python, selenium, tabs, pageload, document-ready

I am trying to change the browser tab while the current tab I am in is loading some javascript. When I try to do that, my program stops in the `driver.switch_to.window(x)`
line and stays there until the javascript is loaded. I would like to know If there is any way not to block the execution.

It's like the driver it's busy, and will not do the action until it finishes.

Comment: There's a way to do it by changing page load strategy but I don't know it offhand. Pyppeteer might be a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

***No***, you can't change the browser tab using `driver.switch_to.window(x)` while in the current tab the page is loading some javascript.

---

### Deep Dive

When you invoke *`get()`* the the client (i.e. the Web Browser) returns back the control to the WebDriver instance once `'document.readyState'` equals to **`"complete"`** is achieved. Till then you won't be able to execute any command through the WebDriver.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Is there a way with python-selenium to wait until all elements of a page has loaded?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47833358/7429447)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So, is there any way to switch the window without waiting for the "complete"?

Comment: @PereColl Precisely **No**. Check the reference discussion for more details.