# Best way to automate a page and check if it is loaded correctly

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor, pageload

I am looking to verify if this page loads correctly - http://www2.hm.com/en_ca/women.html

These are the things I think it would be best to verify if the page is loaded correctly, please let me know if I am missing anything

1) Verify all the links on this page works?

2) Verify if the menu on the top is loaded correctly, Do I need to verify the menu names?

3) Check if the classes are loaded properly?

4) get/post request status 200 and other ajax calls?

Comment: Best way it is not check all things that you wrote. You should have explicit waiters before common actions (e.g. click, type etc.). So you expect to see something not after an action but before. Hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your question  a seperate test to *check if the page is loaded correctly* will be a complete **overhead** because the *Client* (i.e. the *Web Browser*) will never return the *Execution Control* back to the *WebDriver* instance until and unless **'document.readyState' is equal to "complete"**. Once this condition is fulfilled Selenium performs the next line of code.

You can find a detailed discussion on this topic in [*Selenium IE WebDriver only works while debugging*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709234/selenium-ie-webdriver-only-works-while-debugging/47710701#47710701)

Next as you want to *Verify if all the links on this page works or not* , you can write a `function()` and invoke the `function()` whereever required.

Moving on to next question, there is no necessity to *Verify if the menu on the top is loaded correctly or not* as you can't test each and every aspect of each and every *WebElement* present on a *WebPage*. The best approach would be to verify and validate the attributes of only those elements with whom we need to interact.

Again *Checking if the classes are loaded properly* will be a overhead as **JVM** takes care of it in the best possible way.

Finally, to validate *get/post request status 200* you have to write *Tests* as per your requirement.