# Best way to deal with slow pageloads after GET using Selenium

Tags: selenium, timeout, wait, pageloadstrategy, pageloadtimeout

What is the best way to deal with `driver->get(URL)` and slow page load?

I basically have a for loop that runs 3 times at most. Within that loop, I have a `try/catch block. In the try block, it loads the page with get OR`

```
wait()->until(WebDriverExpectedCondition::presenceOfElementLocated(WebDriverBy::xPath("//body")));
```

If the get or the wait doesn't work, the page refreshes or the same get command is executed.

Is that truly the best way? I wonder how you guys deal with that? A page that doesn't load properly seems to be one of the main reasons my script regularly doesn't execute fully.

Answer (score 0):

[presenceOfElementLocated()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for *BODY* won't ensure if the [page have completely loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327132/do-we-have-any-generic-function-to-check-if-page-has-completely-loaded-in-seleni/50329056#50329056).

An ideal solution to slow [pageloads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48737103/best-way-to-automate-a-page-and-check-if-it-is-loaded-correctly/48740519#48740519) would be to set [*pageLoadTimeout()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591282/pageloadtimeout-in-selenium-not-working/45648881#45648881) through a *`try-catch{}`* block as follows:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
try {
    driver.get("https://www.booking.com/hotel/in/the-taj-mahal-palace-tower.html?label=gen173nr-1FCAEoggJCAlhYSDNiBW5vcmVmaGyIAQGYATG4AQbIAQzYAQHoAQH4AQKSAgF5qAID;sid=338ad58d8e83c71e6aa78c67a2996616;dest_id=-2092174;dest_type=city;dist=0;group_adults=2;hip_dst=1;hpos=1;room1=A%2CA;sb_price_type=total;srfid=ccd41231d2f37b82d695970f081412152a59586aX1;srpvid=c71751e539ea01ce;type=total;ucfs=1&#hotelTmpl");
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    System.out.println("TimeoutException occurred. Quiting the program.");
}
driver.quit();
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions on [*pageLoadTimeout()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57659931/unable-to-catch-timeoutexception-from-pageloadtimeout-and-refresh-page-using-sel/57660197#57660197) in:

- [pageLoadTimeout is not working in Selenium - Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52726804/pageloadtimeout-is-not-working-in-selenium-java/52735260#52735260)
- [How to set the timeout of 'driver.get' for python selenium 3.8.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47694922/how-to-set-the-timeout-of-driver-get-for-python-selenium-3-8-0/47695227#47695227)

Comment: that would kill the script immediately if there is a timeout. If a slower connection needs to load over 10 pages that would mean a successful run will hardly every happen. Do you build a loop around it with a refresh in the catch, trying to reload the page for example?