# Unable to enter text in a text field

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, robotframework

For a particular text box on the page the robotframework is giving me an error that the element is not visible after I use the run command. I am basically trying to enter text in a text field but it cannot identify its location on the page.

I used locators..xpath, id and class.

```
xpath=//*[@id="solution-input"]
```

The test case I have written using robot framework:

```
Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//*[@id="solution-input"]    20  seconds
Set Focus To Element    xpath=//*[@id="solution-input"]
Input Text    xpath=//*[@id="solution-input"]    test
```

HTML Snippet:

```
<input _ngcontent-c2="" class="col-md-6 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" id="solution-input" placeholder="Used for Opportunity Name &amp; Description" type="text">
```

Comment: provide the code that you tried and the HTML snippet of the webelement that you are trying to access.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Check the Stack Overflow's [help on asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) first, please. Focus on [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Please have a read through [ask], and especially how to create a [mcve]. As your question stands, it is very difficult to give you an answer.

Comment: sure I will take a look at it Dawid. Sorry, I am new.

Comment: @Johnny any code accompanying your question should be appropriately edited into the question itself, not pasted in an unreadable form into a comment.

Comment: Ok - I realized it later and made the change. I have also deleted it from the comment section now.

Comment: @SiKing - I made some changes. Please let me know

Comment: Your question talks exclusively about robot framework, but you included tag [tag:selenium-webdriver]. Why? Also: "...a particular text box on the page..." could be pretty much anything anywhere; you will have to provide details.

Comment: Because I am using Selenium Web Driver library. The text box is a like a search text box. I further found out that no elements on that page are being able to be located because the focus is not moving onto the next page. So now I this is the issue. Once we get the focus on the page we can locate the elements.

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element so you can use either/both (clubbing up) of the solutions:

- `Wait Until Element Is Visible`:

  ```
  Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//input[@class="col-md-6 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" and @id="solution-input"]    20  seconds
  Set Focus To Element    xpath=//*[@id="solution-input"]
  Input Text    xpath=//*[@id="solution-input"]    test
  ```
- `Wait Until Element Is Enabled`:

  ```
  Wait Until Element Is Enabled    xpath=//input[@class="col-md-6 ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-valid" and @id="solution-input"]    20  seconds
  Set Focus To Element    xpath=//*[@id="solution-input"]
  Input Text    xpath=//*[@id="solution-input"]    test
  ```
- You can find a detailed discussion about `Wait Until Element Is Visible` and `Wait Until Element Is Enabled` in [Robotframework: Selenium2Lib: Wait Until (…) Keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948930/robotframework-selenium2lib-wait-until-keywords/48963864#48963864)
- Reference: [Selenium2Library](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Shortcuts)