# How to click a row that has javascript on click event in RIDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver, robotframework

I am trying to click a row that has a javascript onclick function in RIDE IDE by using Robot Frame Work with Selenium2 library.

```
<tr class="lstrow" onclick="javascript:selectItem(this);" onmouseover="javascript:this.className='rowhover';" onmouseout="javascript:this.className='row';">
```

When i perform click event at following xpath, it says element at path not found.

> //*[@id="myList"]/tbody/tr[0]

By inspecting the element, I can confirm this row is there. Also tried to pin point the 'rowhover' class at this xpath but still not successful. Not even sure if I really can select a specific class at a specific xpath.

> //*[@id="myList"]/tbody/tr[0][contains(@class,'rowhover')] //Not sure if it is right

Comment: There is no class `rowhover` in the html you provided. There is `rowhover` as part of the `onmouseover` attribute.

Comment: For the first expression, try adding some wait and check the element is not in `<ifram>` tag.

Comment: Upon inspecting the element, I can confirm there is no <ifram> tag. Can't test with testing framework right now but will be able to confirm a bit later.

Comment: @LearningCurve , try to remove `tbody` from XPath: `//*[@id="myList"]//tr`

Comment: @Guy this table is in a modal window that opens in an iframe. Also, tried to get the xpath of the table but it returns null but when I xpath table row, it returns me the row. Any suggestion how I can resolve this situation.

Comment: @LearningCurve You need to switch to the `<iframe>` first. As for the `xpath` the html you posted is not enough to tell if the `xpath` is correct.

Comment: @Guy Unfortunately, I can't past all of the html here. it is an old vb.net application where a model window is injected in an iframe. Let's say ifram name is 'myiFrame' and there are couple of nested div's (first level div id='div1', second level div id= 'div2') before that html table (id = 'table1'). Will you please advise how I can build the xpath for this sort of situation?

Comment: @LearningCurve Start with switching to the `<iframe>`, nothing will work without it. For the `xpath` there isn't enough information, but if you have `id` you should use it.

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so you need to induce *wait* and you can use either/both (clubbing up) of the following solutions:

- Python Solution

  - `Wait Until Element Is Visible`:

    ```
    Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath=//tr[@class="lstrow"]    20  seconds
    Set Focus To Element    xpath=//tr[@class="lstrow"]
    # invoke click
    ```
  - `Wait Until Element Is Enabled`:

    ```
    Wait Until Element Is Enabled    xpath=//tr[@class="lstrow"]    20  seconds
    Set Focus To Element    xpath=//tr[@class="lstrow"]
    # invoke click
    ```
- You can find a detailed discussion about `Wait Until Element Is Visible` and `Wait Until Element Is Enabled` in [Robotframework: Selenium2Lib: Wait Until (…) Keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948930/robotframework-selenium2lib-wait-until-keywords/48963864#48963864)
- Reference: [Selenium2Library](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Shortcuts)