# How to resolve the error "Element with locator 'name:ide_username' not found." using Selenium and RobotFramework

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, robotframework, webdriverwait

*** Settings ***

```
Library  SeleniumLibrary
```

*** Variables ***

```
${Browser}  Firefox
${URL}  https://allegis.ramcocloud.com/RVW/extui/vwrt/LaunchPanel.htm
```

*** Test Cases ***

```
TC1 Browser Start and close
    Open Browser  ${URL}  ${Browser}
    Input Text  name:ide_username  INR004914
    Input Text  xpath://input[@name='ide_password']  tsip890*()
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the error is on the first 'Input Text'.
try to copy its xpath like the instruction you made below

```
 Input Text  xpath://input[@name='ide_username']  INR004914
```

Comment: its not able to locate element for this line "Input Text  name:ide_username  INR004914" maybe because of timing problem. So i am not getting the way in which  it can locate the elements

Answer (score 0):

Seems you were close. The desired element is a [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled element so you need to induce *wait* and you can use either/both (clubbing up) of the waiters and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Inducing `Wait Until Element Is Visible`:

  ```
  TC1 Browser Start and close
      Open Browser  ${URL}  ${Browser}
      Wait Until Element Is Visible    xpath://input[@id='ide_username' and @name='ide_username']    20  seconds
      Input Text  xpath://input[@id='ide_username' and @name='ide_username']  INR004914
      Input Text  xpath://input[@name='ide_password']  tsip890*()
  ```
- Inducing `Wait Until Element Is Enabled`:

  ```
  TC1 Browser Start and close
      Open Browser  ${URL}  ${Browser}
      Wait Until Element Is Enabled    xpath://input[@id='ide_username' and @name='ide_username']    20  seconds
      Input Text  xpath://input[@id='ide_username' and @name='ide_username']  INR004914
      Input Text  xpath://input[@name='ide_password']  tsip890*()
  ```

> You can find a detailed discussion about `Wait Until Element Is Visible` and `Wait Until Element Is Enabled` in [How to click a row that has javascript on click event in RIDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52815184/how-to-click-a-row-that-has-javascript-on-click-event-in-ride/52815484#52815484)

---

### Reference

A couple of references:

- [Robotframework: Selenium2Lib: Wait Until (…) Keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948930/robotframework-selenium2lib-wait-until-keywords/48963864#48963864)
- [Selenium2Library](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Shortcuts)