# ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable in Robot Framework

Tags: python, selenium, robotframework, element, webdriverwait

Example code:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-modal="AlertSubmitApproval" id="btn_close_modal">ตกลง</button>
</div>
```

I try to click the button `id="btn_close_modal"` but it seems like the button is not visible then robot response `ElementNotVisibleException: Message: element not interactable`, in spite of the fact I able to click by manual.

My robot code:

```
Request approve
Selenium2Library.Click Element   &{Landing}[reqApprove]
Sleep   2s
Selenium2Library.Click Element   &{Landing}[cofReq]
Sleep   2s
Selenium2Library.Wait Until Page Contains Element     id=btn_close_modal    timeout=20s
Sleep   3s
Selenium2Library.Click Element   id=btn_close_modal
```

How can I able to click the button `id=btn_close_modal`, please could anyone help.

Comment: Is it possible that the element id is not unique?

Comment: @A. Kootstra  It's really not unique, thank you that you made me think about that, now it work by  //button[@id='btn_close_modal' and @data-modal="AlertSubmitApproval"]

Answer (score 4):

The desired element is within a *Modal Dialog Box* so you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be visible/enabled* and you can use either/both (clubbing up) of the following solutions:

- `Wait Until Element Is Visible`:

  ```
  Request approve
  Selenium2Library.Click Element   &{Landing}[reqApprove]
  Sleep   2s
  Selenium2Library.Click Element   &{Landing}[cofReq]
  Sleep   2s
  Selenium2Library.Wait Until Element Is Visible     xpath=//button[@class="btn btn-primary btn-block" and @id="btn_close_modal"]    timeout=20s
  Sleep   3s
  Selenium2Library.Click Element   xpath=//button[@class="btn btn-primary btn-block" and @id="btn_close_modal"]
  ```
- `Wait Until Element Is Enabled`:

  ```
  Request approve
  Selenium2Library.Click Element   &{Landing}[reqApprove]
  Sleep   2s
  Selenium2Library.Click Element   &{Landing}[cofReq]
  Sleep   2s
  Selenium2Library.Wait Until Element Is Enabled     xpath=//button[@class="btn btn-primary btn-block" and @id="btn_close_modal"]    timeout=20s
  Sleep   3s
  Selenium2Library.Click Element   xpath=//button[@class="btn btn-primary btn-block" and @id="btn_close_modal"]
  ```
- You can find a detailed discussion about `Wait Until Element Is Visible` and `Wait Until Element Is Enabled` in [Robotframework: Selenium2Lib: Wait Until (…) Keywords](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948930/robotframework-selenium2lib-wait-until-keywords/48963864#48963864)
- Reference: [Selenium2Library](http://robotframework.org/Selenium2Library/Selenium2Library.html#Shortcuts)

Answer (score 0):

try using this,

```
Click Element       //button[@id='btn_close_modal']
```

or try using java script executor,

```
Wait Until Page Does Not Contain   NOBODY SELECTED
Execute JavaScript  $("#btn_close_modal").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : if Error element not interactable in the robot selenium frame work to button or checkbox  etc..

Execute JavaScript   $(id=btn_close_modal).click()

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Press keys instead of Click Element.
Press Keys    locator_here    ENTER
or Press Keys    locator_here    SPACE

Answer (score 0):

If the other answers do not help, try running the test on another monitor or in headless mode.

For me, the error appeared when running the test browser on a 1440p monitor but everything was fine with `headlesschrome` or on a 1080p monitor.