# element not found error while trying to click a Kendo UI control

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, robotframework, webdriverwait

robot framework not identifying kendo button

when i try click on kendo button, robotframework throws "element not found" error. I tried with selenium also. Response is same.

Tried below xpaths,

```
    xpath://*[@id='btn-ctrl-grp']//span[contains(text(),'WARM')]

    //*[@id='btn-ctrl-grp']/li[3]/span

    xpath://*[contains(text(),'WARM')]
```

my html page contains below kendo elements

```
    <li id="header-col5">

        <div id="header-navigation">

            <ul id="btn-ctrl-grp" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;" data- 
             role="buttongroup" class="km-widget km-buttongroup k-widget 
             k-button-group">

            <li class="btn-ctrl ng-binding ctrl-btn-inactive k-button km- 
            button" ng-disabled="reqCtrlMode == 1 || header.appStatus == 
            'INACTIVE'" ng-class="onButtonClass">

            <span class="k-text km-text">ON</span></li>

            <li class="btn-ctrl ng-binding k-button km-button ctrl-btn- 
            offbtn k-state-active km-state-active" ng- 
            disabled="reqCtrlMode == 0 || header.appStatus == 'INACTIVE'" 
            ng-class="offButtonClass" disabled="disabled">

            <span class="k-text km-text">OFF</span></li>

            <li class="btn-ctrl ng-binding ctrl-btn-inactive k-button km- 
            button" ng-disabled="reqCtrlMode == 11 || header.appStatus == 
            'INACTIVE'" ng-class="warmButtonClass">

            <span class="k-text km-text">WARM</span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
```

can anyone guide me on how to handle kendo controls in robotframework?

Comment: Both first two locators look ok, they should match it (the 3rd is too broad, will match all elements in that branch). Are you sure this html is not in a frame?

Comment: No. Its not inside any new frame. I can access elements next to this kendo buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To `click()` on the kendo button with text as **WARM** you can use the following *xpath* based solution:

```
//ul[@class='km-widget km-buttongroup k-widget k-button-group' and @id='btn-ctrl-grp']//span[@class='k-text km-text' and text()='WARM']
```

**Note**: The element is an [Angular](https://angular.io/) element, so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable*

Comment: Thanks. I'm able to find the element. But its failing to click. I can see click is happening, but the popup is not coming up.I faced similar issue with selenium on IE 11 in WIN 10 (click fails on WIN 10 IE11). But it works fine in Win 7 IE 11. Same issue is there with robot framework as well?

Comment: I don't do [tag:robotframework] much, perhaps this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48948930/robotframework-selenium2lib-wait-until-keywords/48963864#48963864) can help you.

Comment: That locator is REALLY bad and brittle. `//ul[@id='btn-ctrl-grp']//span[.='WARM']` would be enough to locate that element.