# Can't click on dropdown using xpath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I tried to click on the link 'Бренд', but it didn't work. What did I do wrong?

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='filter-title' and text()='Бренд']")).getText()  -works
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='filter-title' and text()='Бренд']")).getText() - doesn't work. Why?
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qZMAp.png)

Comment: You have identically same lines of code, how is it possible that one works and other doesn't?

Comment: to be able to click an element it should be visible, and not 'covered' by another element. It's possible you need to add a delay before doing a click action, to make sure element is fully visible

Answer (score 1):

It is pretty much possible that the line with `WebElement.getText()` would work but the line with `WebElement.click()` won't work as follows :

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='filter-title' and text()='Бренд']")).getText() //works 
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='filter-title' and text()='Бренд']")).click() //doesn't work.
```

### Explaination

The reason for this behavior is when the *Client* (i.e. the *Web Browser*) returns back the control to the *WebDriver* instance once **'document.readyState'** equals to **"complete"** is achieved, it is quite possible that the intended *WebElement* is **present** *(element is present but does not necessarily mean that the element is interactable)*  and **visible** i.e. *(element is visible and also has a height and width that is greater than 0)*. So you were able to extract the text **Бренд**.

But the *WebElement* being **present** and **visible** but doesn't garuntees that the *WebElement* is also **clickable** i.e. **interactable**.

Here you can find a detailed discussion on [*'document.readyState' equal to "complete"*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709234/selenium-ie-webdriver-only-works-while-debugging/47710701#47710701)

### Solution

To click on the *WebElement* with text as **Бренд** you have to induce *WebDriverWait* as follows :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='filter-title' and text()='Бренд']"))).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am able to extract the information correctly from your image, then the class is already a unique identifier. You can just use `driver.findElement(By.className("brand")).click();`.

This should work if the secondary class "brand" is not used anywhere else. If this doesn't work then just take the class of the div that contains it:

```
driver.findElement(By.className("initialDivClass")).findElement(By.className("brand")).click();
```