# How do I get URL if page isn't completely loaded and my webdriver desired waiting time is already over?

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, pageload, webdriverwait

I've been trying to extract the URL if the page hasn't finished loading but I want the URL if driver wait time(10 sec) is over and moves to throw a custom exception.
I've tried `window.location.href`, `window.location.pathname`, etc but they returns null.

Comment: It seems like that Javascript API's don't reflect the current URL until the page is loaded. I've witnessed some odd behavior with iOS when I was debugging early Angular digest cycles where the location property wasn't immediately updated.

How are you setting the URL? That would be where I would look. Is this a result of a redirect? How is the browser getting into a state where there's an "unknown" navigation event that wasn't triggered by your webdriver code?

Answer (score 0):

### Window Location

The *JavaScript* [`window.location`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) object can be used to get the current page address (URL) and to redirect the browser to a new page. The `window.location` object can be written without the window prefix. Some examples:

- `window.location.href`: returns the href (URL) of the current page
- `window.location.hostname`: returns the domain name of the web host
- `window.location.pathname`: returns the path and filename of the current page
- `window.location.protocol`: returns the web protocol used (http: or https:)
- `window.location.assign`: loads a new document

---

### Page completely not loaded

Unfortunately, there is **no** generic step to check if page has completely loaded through Selenium. However there are certain approaches to ensure that the page is completely loaded using the following strategies:

- [`pageLoadStrategy`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43734797/page-load-strategy-for-chrome-driver-updated-till-selenium-v3-12-0/43737358#43737358)
- Wait for the *Browser Client* attaining ['document.readyState' equal to "complete"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709234/selenium-ie-webdriver-only-works-while-debugging/47710701#47710701)
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) inconjunction with [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) as:

  - [`urlContains()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#urlContains-java.lang.String-): The expectation for the URL of the current page to contain specific text.
  - [`urlMatches()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#urlMatches-java.lang.String-): The expectation for the URL to match a specific regular expression
  - [`urlToBe()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#urlToBe-java.lang.String-): The expectation for the URL of the current page to be a specific url.

> **Note**: You can find a detailed discussion in [Do we have any generic funtion to check if page has completely loaded in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50327132/do-we-have-any-generic-funtion-to-check-if-page-has-completely-loaded-in-seleniu/50329056#50329056)